# .htaccess using special regex char

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^some-([\d_\|]+)$ index.php?pageId=SOME&value=$1 [L]
```

This giving error.
I want get an url  : **some-1430427600|1433019600**
How can I get this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteRule ^some-(.+)/?$ index.php?pageId=SOME&value=$1 [NE,NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: not working so giving same error :   "some-1430427601|433019600 is forbidden"